# Authenticate via Graph API without an app secret or an app certificate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-graph

Sorry for the lazy and not well formulated question.

Is it possible to authenticate via Graph API without an app secret or an app certificate **via PowerShell** withiut being a tenant admin? I was on a call with a Microsoft representative and they said that anyone in the company **with PowerShell skills** can authenticate via Graph API and start working with SharePoint or other endpoints like OneDrive. Is it true? I can't figure out how that would be possible.

Is there some kind-of an App registration with delegated permissions that anyone can use? If that's the case, is there a PowerShell example of how the authentication would work?

**Update**

What I am trying to understand if anyone can authenticate with Graph API **via PowerShell** *without* talking to the Azure/Tenant administrators first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could install the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/installation

Delegated access is supported in the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK, please refer to this article for more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/get-started

Comment: I'm still not sure how it works. Suppose I have an App registration with Delegated permissions. How can I authenticate via PowerShell using this specific app? What parameters am I supposed to use for the `Connect-MgGraph` commandlet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your users do this all day long in order to make calls to the Graph (i.e. by visiting Delve). Username + password is one method of authentication. They're limited by the permissions the user holds provided the app is using Delegated permissions.

Comment: Thank you Trevor. Is there an example of how a common user would access Graph API via PowerShell? Next time I'll take more time to formualte the question better.